# Python modulenotfound error - Is there a "pip" alternative way to install python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run a program (obviously written in python) and it requires some python modules. One of the missed modules is aiomultiprocess. I tried installing it with `pip install aiomultiprocess` `pip3 install aiomultiprocess` `python3.7 -m pip install aiomultiprocess` but they all come back with the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/_ctypes.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ffi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffi'
```

No ffi module?! Let's get it!
I looked it up and figured it's a foreign library that come, in the case of python, as 2 forms: CFFI & LibFFI, but "ffi" doesn't exist for python. I installed `cffi` `libffi` and added them to this path `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`, but it changed nothing.

So my question is there another way to install python modules without the need of `pip`??!

Comment: `_ctypes.py` seems odd. I think that should be a shared library such as `_ctypes.cpython-37-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. Maybe a different package installed a rouge module? Could could see if there is any identifying information in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/_ctypes.py`. Just speculation.

Comment: @tdelaney: And a *very* rogue module at that; third party packages should always install into `site-packages`, not the root `lib/pythonX.Y` directory. My own Python 3.8 installation has no `_ctypes.py` anywhere in the `lib/python3.8` tree (`lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` exists, and is what gets loaded when you do `import _ctypes`).

Comment: @tdelaney actually i added `_ctypes.py` manually. why? i kept getting this error `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'` so i had to install `_ctypes`

Comment: @ShadowRanger - It is puzzling. I can't figure out how `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/` is in the path either.

Comment: @FelippeStruc: Sounds like you've got a borked installation of Python.

Comment: @tdelaney: It would be normal for it to be in the path (`/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` are both valid places for the root of a Python install). The problem is why `_ctypes.py` is there, and apparently the answer is "the OP got it from some random place to fix a problem without understanding the cause".

Comment: That's your own module? `_ctypes` is implemented in `_ctypes.c` in the source tree and compiled, at least on linux systems, to a .so shared library. I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve with the replacement.

Comment: @tdelaney @ShadowRanger yeah i probably shouldn't install `_ctypes.py`. What would more efficient: install the .so shared library or remove python and reinstall it?

Comment: If the .so has gone missing I'd be worried about the install and would favor a scorched earth policy. Burn it down and install again.

Comment: @tdelaney just so i don't go down that road again, what would be the exact steps for that?

Comment: It depends on how you got it. If this is linux and it was part of the base operating system install... you've got a problem. You may find that critial system services are using python while you are trying to uninstall. So, not sure what to do. This is a good question for serverfault.com.

Comment: Maybe you go to your package manager, select the already installed python stuff and say reinstall.

Comment: On serverfault you could just say that your python's _ctype-xxx.so has gone missing.

Comment: @tdelaney just did, thanks! Btw, python3.7 isn't the default...i installed it manually because the default is outdated.

Comment: Since its not the default, a complete uninstall / reinstall would be good. Stuff installed via rpm/deb removes automatically. Do any pip uninstall first. And then rm -f 3.7 specific directories.